# Connecting Flink SQL Client to Flink Cluster on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, apache-flink, kubernetes-helm, flink-sql

I have set up a Flink Cluster on Kubernetes using Terraform and Helm.I used Flink Operator and I have also download the Flink SQL Client to my machine separately.

```
resource "helm_release" "flink_operator" {
  name       = "flink-kubernetes-operator"
  repository = "https://downloads.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-1.7.0/"
  chart      = "flink-kubernetes-operator"
  version    = "1.7.0"
}
```

**Question:**
Now, I want to connect the Flink SQL Client to the running Flink Cluster on Kubernetes and execute queries. What are the steps or configurations I need to perform for this connection? Additionally, how can I verify that the SQL Client is correctly connected to the Flink Cluster?

**Details:**

1. My pods:

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
default                cert-manager-5669c8856-k52c7               1/1     Running   0               75m
default                cert-manager-cainjector-56c86fc86f-md559   1/1     Running   0               75m
default                cert-manager-webhook-84fffdf98-fdm4l       1/1     Running   0               75m
default                flink-kubernetes-operator-f4bbff6-5gsv4    2/2     Running   0               72m
kube-system            coredns-5d78c9869d-7vxwh                   1/1     Running   6 (15h ago)     6d20h
kube-system            coredns-5d78c9869d-t7zj9                   1/1     Running   6               6d20h
kube-system            etcd-docker-desktop                        1/1     Running   42 (15h ago)    6d20h
kube-system            kube-apiserver-docker-desktop              1/1     Running   46 (15h ago)    6d20h
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-docker-desktop     1/1     Running   60 (15h ago)    6d20h
kube-system            kube-proxy-nkl2r                           1/1     Running   6               6d20h
kube-system            kube-scheduler-docker-desktop              1/1     Running   116 (62m ago)   6d20h
kube-system            storage-provisioner                        1/1     Running   24 (61m ago)    6d20h
kube-system            vpnkit-controller                          1/1     Running   6               6d20h
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-b887d64f-jg52s        1/1     Running   1               4d
```

2. My services:

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default                cert-manager                     ClusterIP   10.101.223.79   <none>        9402/TCP                 76m
default                cert-manager-webhook             ClusterIP   10.96.19.35     <none>        443/TCP                  76m
default                flink-operator-webhook-service   ClusterIP   10.96.137.93    <none>        443/TCP                  74m
default                kubernetes                       ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                  6d20h
kube-system            kube-dns                         ClusterIP   10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   6d20h
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard             ClusterIP   10.96.230.173   <none>        443/TCP                  4d
```

3. I have successfully set up Flink cluster on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine using the following guides:

- https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/overview/
- https://developer.confluent.io/courses/apache-flink/stream-processing-exercise/

and connect Flink SQL client to flink cluster. I appreciate any guidance or examples on how to achieve this connection successfully. Thank you!